# Undefined reference when adding function to libbluray

Tags: c, makefile

When adding functions to libbluray, and testing it out in the included example, make produces "undefined reference" only for the function added, other functions in the header works fine.

Exact changes like so:

```
src/libbluray/bluray.c：

+void do_stuff()
+{
+    //nothing
+}

src/libbluray/bluray.h:

+void do_stuff(void);

src/examples/index_dump.c:
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
 {
+
+    do_stuff();
+
```

Make error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/examples/index_dump.o: in function `main':
.../libbluray/src/examples/index_dump.c:66: undefined reference to `do_stuff'
```

index_dump.c only include

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bluray.h"
```

This is so very confusing.

Also, `fgrep do_stuff .libs/libbluray.so` shows that `do_stuff` is in the object file.

Comment: Did you recompile the library after adding the function to the source?  If not, that's the trouble.  If it's in the local `.libs` directory, is that the library you're linking with, or are you actually linking with the installed library (which presumably does not have the symbol defined);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Makefile.am` in libbluray contains this (wrapped here):

```
libbluray_la_LDFLAGS= -no-undefined -version-info $(LT_VERSION_INFO) \
  -export-symbols-regex "^bd_"
```

As a result, only symbols starting with `bd_` are exported from the library.  The symbol `do_stuff` does not match this regular expression, so it is not exported and visible outside of the library.

Your `fgrep` check probably picked up the symbol name from debugging information or the regularly symbol table (`.symtab`, not the dynamic symbol table in `.dynsym`).

Comment: Thank you! any ideas on why they would choose to do this instead of declaring them static?

Comment: With `static`, they would have to put everything into a single translation unit (C source file).